# Angular Curly braces not rendering in html

Tags: html, angularjs

In my browser, the value of the angular curly braces is not displayed. There are no errors in the console and the console logs the value, but in my browser its a blank page. However it should say 'hello World' in the top left.

my app.js:

```
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      angular.module('testModule', []);
    }());
```

my controller:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
            .module('testModule')
            .controller('testController', Controller);
        Controller.$inject = [];

        function Controller() {
            var vm = this;        
            vm.test = "hello World";        
            activate();   
            function activate() {
                console.log(vm.test);
            }
        }
    })();
```

my html:

```
<body ng-controller="testController">
    <div>
        {{vm.test}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: how about using $scope ?

Comment: using $scope is apparently bad syntax and they don't allow it where I work. They set it up like this and it always works, but for some reason this doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite this line

```
<body ng-controller="testController">
```

as

```
<body ng-controller="testController as vm">
```

This is because you are using `this` inside your controller and referencing the scope variable with `this` cannot be accessed directly by the Angular expression so you need to create a alias of the controller using `as` you can give it any alias. Then use this alias to access the scope variable. If you use

```
 `<body ng-controller="testController as ctrl">`
```

then you need to access by `{{ctrl.test}}`

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Yes, you missed that. I have edited my answer and added more detail on explanation.

Answer (score 1):

in template update it like; (As you're using controller as syntax)

```
ng-controller="testController as vm"
```

Here's a working plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/tbENuThIIszfe2D2e4qx?p=preview